# Cycle through different DIVs using Next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this code online and its exactly what i need apart from, i need it to have finish button that will submit a form but i cannot manage to get it working

```
Put some code here.
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Ur7SW/36/)

Any ideas you can give me?

Comment: Put a finish button on the last step.

Comment: I have an idea... tell us what you've tried that you can't "manage to get working," and also specifics about what you're trying to achieve with this form.  You'll have better luck doing that than just telling us where we should write some code for you, e.g. "Do my work for me in this spot here."

Comment: well i have tried adding an input field for a submit button (<input type="submit"... etc) in with the prev and next buttons and then a for  tag with an action but then it stops the prev and next buttons working

Comment: i wasnt asking you to write some code for me - when i was putting in the link it said i needed to have code to use the jsfiddle link

Comment: OP, I assume you mean `<form>`, but your Fiddle doesn't show any of that markup. Create a fiddle that shows all of the code you're referencing, so we can better help you sort this out.

Comment: ok - so i have updated the fiddle. this is what i tried in my code but no such luck

Comment: sorry the fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ur7SW/61/

Comment: @charliejsford you forgot to prevent the default action on the next and previous buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/Ur7SW/62/

Comment: hmm - ok that works ok on the fiddle but when i put it on my page it is doing the next/previous buttons as submit buttons :/

Answer (score 0):

This script just cycle through a couple divs.
But you can use the "c" variable to set a value of an hidden form input.
Put your form under the end of `<div class="innerContent">`

```
<form action='YourTargetPage.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' value='3' id='selectedDiv'>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

And add this to the loadContent() jQuery script:

```
$('#selectedDiv').val(c);
```

You will then have a $_POST['selectedDiv'] containing the 'c' value in yourTargetPage.php.

The c variable is zero based since it's the index of an array...
So 0=project 1, 1=Project 2, ect.

The default (onload) value of the hidden input should be the same as the default value of the script `var c = 3;` in case the user select the first project without triggering the loadContent() function.
;)

Comment: My answer is based on your first Fiddle.
I just saw your 2nd... 
Your form should be UNDER the innerContent div.
In your 2nd Fiddle... Your form submits... But submits nothing.